# How to scale image view with different scene size in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

i have an scene with 1024 width in 600 height and i have an image with this size 1800x1022 i add this image to ImageView and call setFitWith & Height to scale it with my scene . but i want if some One click on maximize button the imageVew scale to new size.Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a handler to the `width` and `height` properties of the scene so that anytime a user changes the size of the image (whether it be maximizing or dragging the window to resize it), you can resize the image dynamically:

```
stage.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {@
    Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        //do some meaningful stuff here, 
    }
});
```

And then do your re-sizing of the image inside that.